# Error while running ionic serve - MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I get below error suddenly, when I cleaned my node modules and ran ionic serve.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\xxxx\_work\10\s\xx\ff\dfd\node_modules\ionic'

   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)

   at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)

   at Module.require (module.js:498:17)

   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

   at C:\Users\4333\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic:18:13 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Comment: _when I cleaned my node modules and ran ionic serve_.. did you run `npm install` to install all dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You would have upgraded your ionic to 3, on your new npm install. so you need to install  ionic 2  globally and locally.

Try

```
npm install ionic@2.1.0
```

and

```
npm install -g ionic@2.1.0
```

Check your package.json, change the `"ionic": "^2.1.0"` to `"ionic": "2.1.0"`